# c# emgucv HoughLines function

Tags: c#, function, emgucv

I need to do a HoughLines to the bitmap pic:
[image]
but  the result is an error:

> the array is out of range

How can I draw the line in the picture?

Comment: show us the code you have tried so far

Comment: at wihch line you get the error?